# How do I make a copy of an array with one difference?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the function to make a copy of an array with the exception it has the mouse position in it. This is my code so far.

```
mousearray = originalarray;
mousearray[mousex][mousey] = "Your mouse is here";
```

This doesn't work if I loop it every frame, it seems like the original array gets changed too. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by loop it every frame?

Comment: How does your originalarray look like ? Could you please show the data?

Comment: `mousearray` is just a reference to that original array. So any changes to it will affect the original array. What you need to do is create a copy of the original array then perform your operations on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
mousearray = originalarray;
```

`mousearray` doesn't become a copy of that array, it just is a new reference to the same array, thus changing `mousearray` also changes `originalarray` cause it is the same.

To truly make a copy, there are two ways:

```
mousearray= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalarray));
// or
mousearray = _.cloneDeep(originalarray);
```

Note that the second way requires that you install lodash (npm package).

Answer (score 1):

You can use array destructuring.

```js
const originalArray = [1,2,3,4];
const copyArray = [...originalArray];
///
copyArray.push('hello');
console.log(copyArray); // --> [1,2,3,4,'hello']
console.log(originalArray); // --> [1,2,3,4]
```

---

Edit:
Another way is to use `concat`. If you are on an older browser you should prefer this method:

```js
const originalArray = [1,2,3,4];
const copyArray = [].concat(originalArray);
///
copyArray.push('hello');
console.log(copyArray); // --> [1,2,3,4,'hello']
console.log(originalArray); // --> [1,2,3,4]
```

---

Edit 2: Since above methods only make a new array instance with virtually same elements. It does not create a true copy. If array has objects, then `destructuring` or `concat` methods will copy the references only. There are two ways you can create a true copy.

1. Use a recursive solution to create separate instances of children as well. Often you will find such a solution in libraries like `lodash` or `jQuery`.
2. Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))` hack. Note that this is just a hack and does not always work (esp. if your array or object has circular references).

Comment: This probably will not work because original array is a multi dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

**Multidimensional Array** copy with new

```js
var oldArray = [
  ["a","b", {id:1}],
  ["x", "y", ["Role", "Dev"]]
];

// clone "old" Array
var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArray));

newArray[0][0] = "GMK";
newArray[0][1] = "Hussain";

console.log('OLD ARRAY')
console.log(oldArray)

console.log('NEW ARRAY')
console.log(newArray)
```

Short and **simplest** solution with `concat`

```js
var oldArray = ["a","b"];

var newArray = ["new"];

var oldAndNewArray = [...oldArray].concat(newArray);

console.log( oldAndNewArray );
```